# Why doesn't PostGIS use gist index when doing a ST_DUMP(ST_UNION)?

Tags: postgis, spatial-index, union

My query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT *, ST_BUFFER(the_geom::GEOGRAPHY, 3000)::GEOMETRY AS buffer FROM af_modis_master LIMIT 20000;
CREATE INDEX idx_tmp_the_geom ON tmp USING gist(buffer); 
EXPLAIN SELECT (DUMP(ST_UNION(buffer))).path[1], (DUMP(ST_UNION(buffer))).geom FROM tmp;
```

Output from EXPLAIN:

```
Aggregate  (cost=1705.52..1705.54 rows=1 width=32)
  ->  Seq Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..1625.01 rows=16101 width=32)
```

Seq Scan means it is not using the index, right? Why not?

UPDATE: Even adding a where clause that filters based on the buffer causes a Seq Scan:

```
ANALYZE tmp;
EXPLAIN SELECT (DUMP(ST_UNION(buffer))).path[1], (DUMP(ST_UNION(buffer))).geom FROM tmp WHERE ST_XMIN(buffer) = 0.0;
```

(This question was also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875901/postgis-query-not-using-gist-index-when-doing-a-st-dumpst-union). Apologies for cross-posting but the community there is a bit more active (maybe just on PostGIS query topics?), so perhaps wil provide an answer quicker.)

Comment: don't cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875901/postgis-query-not-using-gist-index-when-doing-a-st-dumpst-union

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did apologize in the StackOverflow question. It seemed that this community is less active than the StackOverflow community, maybe just on PostGIS query topics?

Comment: No biggie. Generally, PostGIS questions do well at gis.SE, while pure SQL questions are better put to SE. This one fits in between.

Answer (score 6):

An index is used to filter a query using the "WHERE" part of the statement. A GiST index is not used by ST_Union. Without a "WHERE" part, then no filtering (or index) is required to return the result, and the query just chugs through all the rows in the query.

[As described in the manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#id372735), not all functions make use of indicies, for example ST_Distance and ST_XMin don't benefit from a spatial index. Other spatial functions make use of a GiST index if the query would benefit from it. For example, with my test data:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Union(buffer))).path[1], (ST_Dump(ST_Union(buffer))).geom FROM tmp
WHERE ST_DWithin(buffer,  ST_MakeEnvelope(90900, 190900, 100100, 200100), 100);

Aggregate  (cost=8.53..8.55 rows=1 width=2272)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_tmp_the_geom on tmp  (cost=0.00..8.52 rows=1 width=2272)
        Index Cond: (buffer && '0103000000010000000500000000000000002BF64000000000804A074100000000002BF6400000000040700841000000008076F8400000000040700841000000008076F84000000000804A074100000000002BF64000000000804A0741'::geometry)
        Filter: (('01030000000100000005000000000000004031F64000000000A04D0741000000004031F64000000000206D0841000000004070F84000000000206D0841000000004070F84000000000A04D0741000000004031F64000000000A04D0741'::geometry && st_expand(buffer, 100::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(buffer, '01030000000100000005000000000000004031F64000000000A04D0741000000004031F64000000000206D0841000000004070F84000000000206D0841000000004070F84000000000A04D0741000000004031F64000000000A04D0741'::geometry, 100::double precision))
```

Comment: Please see my update. Btw, if you want I can close/delete this question? I wonder if StackExchange has considered a way to post a question in multiple "communities" ie sites so that questions that are relevant to multiple communities do not have to be cross-posted in order to get wider attention?